# How to solve the differential equation of second order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation
$y \dfrac {d^2y} {dx^2} -{(\dfrac {dy} {dx}} ) ^2=0$ .

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\implies \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}\cdot\frac1{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac1y$$

$$\implies \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{dy}y\text{ assuming } dx\ne0$$

$$\implies\ln\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\ln y+C$$

can you take it from here ?

Comment: ya. i can do it now. thank you

Comment: @user59489, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the following substitution:
$$y=\text{e}^{\int u(x)dx}$$ to reduce the order of your OE.

Comment: perfect hint! +1